# Cannot setState from props in React from parent to child

Tags: reactjs, setstate, getderivedstatefromprops

I am trying to pass -from parent to child component- some data as props and **I would like to set this prop to initial state**.

```js
class EditContact extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: this.props.name,
      phone_number: this.props.phone_number,
      address: this.props.address
    };
    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
  }
  ...
}
```

*I am not getting any errors*, but if I `console.log` `this.state.name` I get nothing. or when I check it in chrome-s react add-on *I can see the props values*, but state remains `""`.

I have also tried to sort it with `getDerivedStateFromProps` in `componentDidMount`, I can set it with that but then *it doesn`t let me change the state later* on...Why?! What can be wrong?

Comment: How are you using this `EditContact` component in your app? It might be that you are loading the data in the parent component asynchronously, so when `EditContact` is created the props are not set yet.

Comment: please provide the code where you're trying to `console.log`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the value of props is the expected when you assign them to the state.

```
super(props);
debugger; // This will act as a break point in chrome
```

Most likely the issue is that the value of props is empty by the time they are assigned to the state.

Comment: Yes, that is the issue,but I cannot seem to figure it out how to solve it. I am making a phonebook app. Filtering, sorting, adding, deleting, editing. Everything is done apart from editing. In order to be able to complete the project I should set the initial state to this.props but when it renders it is still empty and I am not sure how to work around it.

Comment: Well you could use componentDidUpdate and do setState there but you have to be carefull and wrap it in a condition or it will cause an infinite loop. Can't you create the component when the props have value? I say this cause since you have to do setState to change the value of props you should be able to control that, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
props.name
```

instead of

```
this.props.name
```